# C# and GSM modem for M2M supervision?

Tags: c#

Is there a class for C# and GSM modem communication. I try to send sms from a device then receiving it on c#.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GSMComm: http://gsmcomm-for-net-2-0.apponic.com/

Take a look at this examples:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem 
(SMS client and server is an application software which is used for sending and receiving messages(SMS))

and

http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/samples.htm (SMS source samples (for GSM phones))